# C / C++ - signed char comparing

Tags: c++, c, comparison, byte, signed

I'm trying to skip the BOM in an UTF-8 encoded file, but my tests in ifs fail :

```
int i = 0;

if( str[i] == '\0xef' ) {
    ++i;
}

if( str[1] == '\0xbb' ) {
    ++i;
}

if( str[2] == '\0xbf' ) {
    ++i;
}
```

I don't know why they don't work. There must be some kind of implicit conversion between signed and unsigned, and Visual Studio displays character codes with 2 octets while debugging, even though i'm using 1 byte chars.

What's going on ? Thank you :)

Comment: `'\0xbf'`  is multibytes char constant

Comment: How is str defined? Is it signed or unsigned char array?

Comment: It's a const char *. I also tried 0xbf instead of '\0xbf' but the result was the same.

Comment: char is signed 8bit, thus its values are within -128..127 range. Note: 0xbf > 127

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be

```
int i = 0;

if( str[i] == 0xef ) {
    ++i;
}

if( str[1] == 0xbb ) {
    ++i;
}

if( str[2] == 0xbf ) {
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried this possibility, but it lead to the same reuslt.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to define hex character constants is `'\xef'`. Your `str` shall stay signed in this case.

```
if( str[i] == '\xef' ) {
    ++i;
}
```

Or you can define `str` as `unsigned char *` and compare against integer 0xef (as proposed by Chinna).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that too, but the if tests failed too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the constant is interpreted as an integer in this context, and thus gets the value 239, while the character is sign-extended. Because `char` is signed on most x86 compilers (including Visual Studio) the bit-pattern `0xef` is interpreted as a negative number and thus, when extended, yields -17. Those two numbers are not equal.

Try doing it this way: `if ((unsigned char)str[i] == '\xef')`.